# why onload event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

here is my codes:

```
$('.classname').on('click',function myfunc() {
  alert ('working ..!');
});
```

the above code works correctly and when I click on the div `.classname`, it gives me a message: `working ..!`

Now I want to use of that function (`myfunc`) for onload event. here is my try:

```
window.onload = myfunc;
window.onload = myfunc();
document.onload = myfunc();
<body onload = "myfunc()">
object.onload=myfunc(){alert ('working ..!');}
```

but none of them does not works. Why ?! Why, when I refresh the page don't see any message ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you define the `myFunc` method ?

Comment: Because myfunc is declared inside the call to on(). You need to declare it outside of there so its scope is global.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload
See this

Comment: @Sushanth-- yes. look my first codes. `function myfunc() {
  alert ('working ..!');
});`

Comment: @Sajad . But looks like that is an anonymous function which is the event handler. Move it out and  declare a function outside it instead.

Comment: @Sushanth-- your mean is I remove this: `$('.classname').on('click',);` ? I did it before asking. won't works.

Comment: @Sushanth-- — It has a name, it isn't anonymous.

Comment: @Sajad From your working code example, It seems that you are using jQuery. If this is the case why don't you try `$( window ).load(function() {
  // function code
});` as given on 'https://api.jquery.com/load-event/'

Comment: @SameerMahant — Because the question is about reusing the existing function, not declaring a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> $('.classname').on('click',function myfunc() {
>   alert ('working ..!');
> });
> ```

You have created a named function using a function expression. You have passed it to `on()`.

Because it is a function expression, you are not creating a variable called `myfunc` in the current scope. It is accessible only from inside itself, and from within the `on` function.

Use a function declaration instead.

```
function myfunc() {
  alert ('working ..!');
}
$('.classname').on('click', myfunc);
$(document).on('load', myfunc);
```

Further reading on [function declarations and expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions) can be found on MDN.

Comment: your example worked correctly. but in reality does not works for my codes. please check out my update ...

Comment: @Sajad — Why would the document's load event have a `(this).attr("href")`? It isn't a link. It's a document.

Comment: ow !!!! I see. that's the problem, ok well, how can I get the end of url ? here is my URL: `www.example.com/contact#test`, now I need to `test`, how can I get that ?

Comment: Read it from [the `location` object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: still I can not get `test` ! should I use of `url.hash` ?

Comment: @Sajad — If you have a new question, then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Provide a link to this one if it helps provide context. Provide a [test case](http://sscce.org/); your comments on my answer don't provide enough information to tell what your new problem is.

Comment: ok, I will aks a new question. but I'm waiting for *your* answer :-) !

Comment: waiting for you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524522/how-can-i-get-hashtag-part-of-the-url-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the function is not global so you need to declare it outside the click event.

Comment: and how can I fix it ?

Comment: regarding scope: it doesn't need to be global, but it does need wider scope that when it's defined inside the 'click' event handler.

Answer (score 0):

what about using `ready` event instead of load? as you can read in jquery documentation :

> .load()
>   Bind an event handler to the “load” JavaScript event.
>
> .ready()
>   Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

In my opinion, the full dom should be fully loaded (ie, size of element already set and computed for scroll...)

```js
function scroll() {
    alert('test');
     return false;
}

$('.link').on('click', scroll);
$(document).on('ready', scroll);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link">manual test</a>
```

**EDIT**
Answer for inital post. Carefull, I saw that you put spaces between prop key and value `<body onload = "myfunc()">` you can't do this. It should be `key=value`

```js
var myfunc = function() {
  alert ('working ..!');
}
```

```html
<body onload="myfunc()">
  <a onclick="myfunc()">manual test</a>
</body>
```

Comment: héhé! thx :)
maybe you can "valid" the answer for other users ;)

Comment: I think you are looking for the word "accept", and since it doesn't solve the problem (either the original one or the extra one added in edits), it shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: @Quentin `ready` seems to wait for all downloads and paintings/renderings to trigger event.... [more info in jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Umm. It *doesn't* wait for the dependancies. The point is that if you are waiting for something, then `load` is more likely to wait long enough than `ready`. Since the OP is trying to scroll to a particular point in the document, it is *desirable* to use `load` over `ready` so that images can be loaded and the document reflowed to accommodate them.  Switching to `ready` is likely to introduce additional problems.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but strangly, `load` don't triggers on tests.  Maybe we should attach the listner to `window` instead of `body` as in jquery recommandation

Comment: "I saw that you put spaces between prop key and value `<body onload = "myfunc()">` you can't do this." — Yes, you can. It is perfectly valid and supported.

Comment: You should attach the `load` listener to `document` as per the answer I gave previously.