# how can I get # hashtag part of the URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

This is my URL:

```
www.example.com/contact#test
```

Now I need to `test`. According to the research, I've found a [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) related to my problem, and I realized that I should use of `hash` for get `test` from my url. something like this:

```js
var url = www.example.com/contact#test;
var anchor = url.hash;
alert(anchor);
```

but when I use of `alert` for `anchor`, it shows me *undefined*. anyway how can I get `test` from my url ?

Comment: That says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`, it doesn't show you `undefined`. Try creating a real test case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the value after hash (#) from a URL using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662693/how-do-i-get-the-value-after-hash-from-a-url-using-jquery)

Comment: @Quentin can I chat with you for a moment  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is using pure JavaScript

```
var hashValue = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do is using split, if your URL has test only after the #. And also nothing other that test after the #.

```js
var url = 'www.example.com/contact#test';
var anchor = url.split('#');
alert(anchor[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = new URL("http://www.example.com/contact#test");
console.log(url.hash.substring(1));
```